# How to install PyGears on Linux

Tags: python, pygears

Is there any instruction on how to install PyGears on Linux? And which distributions are supported?
I tried looking on the official website pygears.org but couldn't find anything regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyGears depends on a few other tools which are dependent on libraries coming with Linux distribution. We are trying to solve this issue and expand the range of supported distributions.

PyGears should be able to run on any Linux normally, but you could get an error because some files are missing, this means that tools used by PyGears are missing some files/packages and those packages should be installed.

We tested PyGears on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and everything works fine, the same should be for versions above 20.04.

**Build essential**

To be able to run all PyGears tools we need to be sure we have all essentials installed, run next commands to get it:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
```

**Installing PyGears**

Install with pip First, make sure that you have pip installed

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

PyGears requires Python 3.6 or higher. Install the PyGears package with the command below.

```
sudo pip3 install -U pygears-tools
```

Next, type this command

```
pygears-tools-install -d
```

If you get error regarding xcb plugin for Qt, to solve this issue type next:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libxcb-xinerama0
```

That should be it. For testing purpose you can use this code:

```
from pygears import gear
from pygears.typing import Ufixp, Uint
from pygears.lib import drv, collect
from pygears.sim import sim, cosim


@gear
def darken(din, *, gain):
    return din * Ufixp[0, 8](gain)


res = []

drv(t=Uint[8], seq=[12, 23, 255]) \
    | darken(gain=0.5) \
    | float \
    | collect(result=res)

cosim('/darken', 'verilator', outdir='./home/stefan/test/output')
sim()

print(res)
```

Change **outdir** to show somewhere in your space and save the file as .py and compile as a standard python file. The output should be something like:

```
-          /darken/mul [INFO]: Running sim with seed: 2631661647950327284
0                      [INFO]: -------------- Simulation start --------------
103                    [INFO]: ----------- Simulation done ---------------
103                    [INFO]: Elapsed: 0.01
[6.0, 11.5, 127.5]
```